# Why is contentView height of UITableViewCell always one point smaller than the UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My cells, at the UITableViewCell level, have a height of 44 points. The contentView says 43 points, and it's greyed out in IB. How can I make the content the same size as the cell?

Note that I'm designing my cells in separate xib files.

I want my cells to have no margin between each other.

I have also set None as separator style of the table view.
Row height in IB is also set to 44 points. Not using any sections.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using **storyboards** setting the `Separator` of the tableView to `None` (instead of `Default`) gets rid of the 1pt separator and the contentView's height becomes equal to the cell's height (even though it's grayed out)

**Note:** This solution doesn't work with xib files (at least doesn't update the IB, didn't check at run-time).

Comment: The issue was not about separators but using the full area of the cell, which is not possible with only adding to the contentView which is always one point less tall than the full cell. Only the backgroundView covers the whole height.

Comment: Did you try what I said before down-voting it? It's 1pt less **only if** the `Separator` is set to `Default`. When the `Separator` is set to `None` the contentView's height becomes equal to the cell's height (the backgroundView as you're referring).

Comment: Are you sure? Because how would a cell know of the separator state in the table view? I also explicitly stated that I already set separator to None. Unless I missed something I don't think the separator and the cell height are related.

Comment: Yes, I am. I checked it before posting and just double checked. From my understanding the contentView is set like: cell.height - separator.height so if the `Separator` is `None` it's getting just the cell's height.

Comment: Okay maybe at runtime what you say is correct. However I'm designing my cells in separate xib files so at that time they should have no idea what kind of tableview they end up in. Well, I'll consider this next time I run into this issue.

Comment: And what I mean is in IB the contentview height is always greyed out.

Comment: I don't know about xib's behavior, but I'm using storyboards and everything works in IB, not a run-time thing.

Comment: Yes, the contentView's height is grayed out, but still updates when I set the `Separator` to `None` in Storyboard, but just checked with a xib file - xib doesn't update. I think it would be helpful to update your question mentioning that this.

Comment: Ok sounds like we found a difference there. You'll have to add the storyboard info to your answer or I can't change rating

Comment: Updated my answer with the additional info regarding storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using full sized background images as background for the cells. As soon as I stopped putting separate UIImageView:s as background in the contentView, and instead assigned the background UIImageView:s to the cell's backgroundView property, and then set the height of the cell as well as the height of each cell in the uitableview (and also set the contentView background color to fully transparent!), things started working as I wanted them to. The contentView height will still be one point smaller, but now the cells align perfectly to each other. For this I don't need to have the contentView height match the UITableViewCell height.